# Increment all Employees Experience by 1, using month-day from date in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

We've all the employee's **DOJ(DATE OF JOIN)** and we need to **increment** all the employee's experience by "1". We've to consider **"sysdate" and "sysdate+7days(week)"** as condition.
whom ever falls in that week his experience should be incremented while considering only "**month and day**" and ignoring year from the dates.

Suppose:- 
`date= 20-08-2015`, we've to `select all records from 20-08(dd-mm) to 26-08(dd-mm) from all the dates ignoring year`.

[image: SampleData]

the expected result can be a dummy column with experience.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please add some sample data (including rows that should _not_ be updated) and the expected result based on that sample data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i've updated the question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is a real beast so first the meat, then the tooth pick:

```
WITH chk AS (
  SELECT to_timestamp('12-28', 'MM-DD') AS dt
), doj_doy AS (
  SELECT workername, workerdoj, extract('doy' from workerdoj) AS doy
  FROM my_table
), date_tails AS (
  -- Get the MM/DD in year 0
  SELECT workername, workerdoj,
         (workerdoj - extract('year' from workerdoj) * interval '1 year') AS date0
  FROM doj_doy
  UNION
  -- Add DOJ early in the year (year +1)
  SELECT workername, workerdoj,
         (workerdoj - (extract('year' from workerdoj) - 1) * interval '1 year') AS date0
  FROM doj_doy
  WHERE doy < 8
)
SELECT workername, workerdoj
FROM date_tails, chk
WHERE date0 BETWEEN dt AND dt + interval '6 days';
```

The whole idea is to throw away the year from the filtering. This is done for all records in the first `SELECT` clause of the third CTE:

```
(workerdoj - extract('year' from workerdoj) * interval '1 year') AS date0
```

This leaves us with a `timestamp` value in the year 0. That result is `UNION`ed for those DOJ in the first week of January, when `doy < 8`, with `doy` having been calculated in the `doj_doy` CTE. This ensures that you include the early January DOJ's when you do a post-Xmas search.

In the first CTE you have to specify the date of the year to search on and then you are good to go. If you want to do this by `current_date` or some other `timestamp` value then you should convert it to a year 0 date as well.

Comment: thanks for the effort @Patrick, but we've to consider leap years also.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    workername, 
    workerobj, 
    DATE_PART('year', current_date) - DATE_PART('year', workerobj) + 1 experience
from emp_tbl
where 
to_date(to_char(workerobj, 'DD-MM'), 'DD-MM') 
between 
to_date(to_char(current_date, 'DD-MM'), 'DD-MM') and
to_date(to_char(current_date + 7, 'DD-MM'), 'DD-MM')
```

`to_char(DOJ, 'DD-MM')` will extract `day-month` from `DOJ`

`to_date(to_char(DOJ, 'DD-MM'), 'DD-MM')` will create a date by adding `0001` as the year.(actual year will be ignored)

Comment: we need to get it in Select statement in a dummy column, i've updated the question please check it. I appreciate your effort  brother :)

Comment: Do this table have a column `experience`.? or dummy experiance clm by datediff between sysdate and doj

Comment: No, we've to use a dummy column using SELECT statement.

Comment: it is calculating for all the records not between 20-08(dd-mm) to 26-08(dd-mm)

Comment: yeah working on that, the issue i'm facing is suppose when day and month are (30-07) , when i'm doing +7 days it is considering (37-07) not (06-08) i.e next month. Thanks brother you gave some idea how to do.

Comment: `to_char(current_date + 7, 'DD-MM')` will give `06-08` if `current_date` is `30-07-xxxx`

Comment: within a year it is working, if the the date are between two years i.e 28-12(for year 2013)  to 28/12+7days = 4-01(i.e next year 2014) in this scenario it is returning 0 records.